# Intercept USSD response

Tags: android, ussd

I'm developing a widget for Android that show the balance (amount of money) that return the USSD code execution. The execution is not the problem, He, I'm developing a widget for Android that show the balance (amount of money) that return the USSD code execution. The execution is not the problem, the problem is how i can intercept the response.

I tried different variants available in Github, [such as this one](https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor), where I had the problem to intercept the response. I also looked at other solutions, but didn't find any to work properly. Please anybody have a solution for that?